# Creating links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want every element which is coming from a group to be a link.How do you use link_to tag over here?

```
<table>
    <% @groups.each do |group|%>
        <tr>
            <td>  <%=group.group_name%> </td>" 
        </tr>
    <%end%> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have routes for `group_path`, please try:

```
<%=link_to group.group_name, group%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax for `link_to` follows this format

> link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

In your case, your code should look like this

```
<%= link_to group.group_name, group_path(group) %>
```

Documentation

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 1):

first all, you can define resouce for group in route file same:

```
resources :groups
```

, so you have group_path method is used in view for creating link
after that at view you do same:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to group.group_name, group_path(group) %></td>
<tr>
```